# can we write script for the button which is inside the popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popover

I have created a popover so that if I click on the image the popover should appear.

The popover is working. what my main problem is I have inserted buttons in the popover.

so I want to write javascript or jquery code for the button when it is clicked. Can anyone help on this?

I have tried but it's not working!!!!

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var x = $(this).attr('class');
    alert(x);
  });
});
$(function() {
  $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    html: true,
    container: 'body',
    content: function() {
      var content = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
      return $(content).children(".popover-body").html();
    },
    title: function() {
      var title = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
      return $(title).children(".popover-heading").html();
    },
    placement: "auto"
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./isobar.js">
</script>


<span>
<img src="./img/more_options_icon.png" data-toggle="popover" tabindex="5" data-trigger="focus" data-popover-content="#moreoptions">
</span>
<div id="moreoptions" class="hidden">
  <div class="popover-body">
    <div class="list-group">
      <button type="button" class="list-group-item"><span class="gap"></span>Edit</button>
      <button type="button" class="list-group-item"><span class="gap"></span>Logic Builder</button>
      <button type="button" class="list-group-item"><span class="gap"></span>Uneploy</button>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think the  `$(function() {` part is correct. Try to delete that function wrapper and leave only the `$('button').click(function() {...}` part.

Comment: @Alberto the `$(function() {})` is fine - it's a shorthand document.ready event handler, which is very necessary for this to work

Comment: You need to write this in ready  function $("[data-toggle=popover]")
.popover({html:true})

Comment: it's not duplicate @peeebeee I have displayed my view I want to write script for the page

Comment: I have updated the code @pArthsavadiya

Comment: If I may, what is stopping you from setting a unique ID for each of these buttons and write its own event handlers (ex: click function)

Comment: Like this example https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/235283/

Answer (score 1):

O.k. Here is an updated version of my answer and checked and working code. A secret of a popover is to fire the correspondence function in a right time with a popover firing. So the JS code is:

```
function firePopover() {
            $('.hidden').css('display', 'block');
            var delay = 100;
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('button:not(.main)').unbind('click');
                $('button:not(.main)').click(function () {
                    var x = $(this).attr('class');
                    alert(x);
                    $('.hidden').css('display', 'none');
                });
            }, delay);
        }
```

Here I an using html selector

```
:not(.main)
```

to prevent binding and unbinding events to the main button. In addition, we have to pay attention on the fact that every popover rising binds a new event handler to each button. This means that after n popover risings every button will fire it's alert n times. To prevent this effect, it is possible to bind events in the first rising only, or as I did, to unbind an event from a button every popover rising. As to html code, here it is:

```
<button class="main" onclick="firePopover()">Fire Popover</button>
<div id="moreoptions" class="hidden" hidden>
    <div class="popover-body">
        <div class="list-group">
            <button class="class-0 list-group-item"><span class="gap"></span>Edit</button>
            <button class="class-1 list-group-item"><span class="gap"></span>Logic Builder</button>
            <button class="class-2 list-group-item"><span class="gap"></span>Uneploy</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I only added the ".main" button to accept a simulation, and each button got additional corresponding class "class-0", "class-1", "class-2" for successful demonstration. Now, when you push on the main button, other 3 buttons appear. And to the contrary, pushing on any of those 3 buttons, is following by alert firing and disappearing of all of them. I hope this will help you.

```js
 function firePopover() {
            $('.hidden').css('display', 'block');
            var delay = 100;
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('button:not(.main)').unbind('click');
                $('button:not(.main)').click(function () {
                    var x = $(this).attr('class');
                    alert(x);
                    $('.hidden').css('display', 'none');
                });
            }, delay);
        }
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

button {
  float: left;
}

.class-0 {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="main" onclick="firePopover()">Fire Popover</button>
    <div id="moreoptions" class="hidden" hidden>
        <div class="popover-body">
            <div class="list-group">
                <button class="class-0 list-group-item"><span class="gap"></span>Edit</button>
                <button class="class-1 list-group-item"><span class="gap"></span>Logic Builder</button>
                <button class="class-2 list-group-item"><span class="gap"></span>Uneploy</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you give fiddle or snippet that works? Thank you

Comment: BTW, only for the tag "input" you should write it's type, not for "button".

Comment: The `type` attribute is not only for `<input>` elements - it’s completely valid to use with `<button>` elements too. In some cases it’s even necessary :o)

Comment: Snippet added to the current example

Comment: This is the same answer I just made it look a little bit nicer https://jsfiddle.net/gcfb0os1/96/

Comment: Yes agrm, you are right - the "type" attribute in a case of "button" has 3 values: button, submit and reset. In other words, it is responsible on an event type. But in this very example the event "onclick" attached by event listener. So this very example does not need this attribute at all. To the contrary, if we are talking about the "input" tag, there this attribute is responsible for the element's layout and it is necessary.

Comment: Thank you hamada147, it seems much nicer. But to say a truth, I personally prefer the short and exact answer - as short as possible and as accurate as possible and nothing superfluous, If these conditions are met, the answer will be much more understandable.

Comment: Thank you for your answers @LeonidZ. but what if I want to change the color of the text in button.